# Fastest way to level faction reputations?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft: Mists of Pandaria, Blizzard have discontinued the model of using faction tabards to level reputation levels for each faction, and instead removed some of the daily quest restrictions.

I have also noticed that killing trash enemies in dungeon instances no longer gives a steady stream of reputation throughout the instance, but that there have been some larger chunks of reputation added during the course of each instance (unsure *what* causes this, but suspect it to be bosses).

With this in mind, what is the fastest way to level faction reputations? Is it just a case of grinding daily quests or is there a new replacement mechanic for tabards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you do all of the faction quests leading up to getting the dailies it will allow you to get more reputation before starting the dailies. As for the fastest way it is going to be dailies, just for the fact that they have removed the 25 daily limit and in return removed the tabards.

Note that with 5.2, you can now gain 300 reputation per day toward a faction of your choice by completing a random heroic dungeon.

Answer (score 0):

Usually doing quicker lower level quests are the easiest way to farm reputation. For example, if I wanted to farm rep for the night-elves I would use my mount and fly and quickly finish low level quests that give reputation. Hope this helps!